# How to instruct a polymorphic functor in a container to do its job and return results?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, functor

I have a `std::vector<>` of pointers to a base functor. This container, a calculator class, should be able to hold onto an arbitrary number of these function objects that calculate arbitrary statistics.

The part I'm struggling with is how to write a method for the container class, that iterates over these pointers, picks the one you're interested in out of hte group, tells it to do its job by calling `operator()`, then returns the result.

Here's some code that illustrates the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> //shared_ptr
#include <vector>

class BaseFunctor{
    virtual double operator()(std::vector<double> inputs) = 0;  
};

class Sum : public BaseFunctor{
    double operator() (std::vector<double> inputs){ 
        double sum (0.0);
        for(auto elem : inputs)
            sum += elem;
        return sum;
    }
};

class Prod : public BaseFunctor{
    double operator() (std::vector<double> inputs){ 
        double sum (1.0);
        for(auto elem : inputs)
            sum *= elem;
        return sum;
    }
};

class Calculator {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseFunctor>> m_stats;
    std::vector<double> m_simple_data;
public:
    Calculator() 
        : m_simple_data({1.0, 2.0, 3.0}) {};
    void addStat(std::shared_ptr<BaseFunctor> stat) { 
        m_stats.push_back(stat); 
    }
    // calculate stat?
};

int main() {

    Calculator calc;
    calc.addStat(std::make_shared<Sum>());
    calc.addStat(std::make_shared<Prod>());
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now, how could I tell `calc` to give me the product, and only the product? Especially when I can't control what statistics the user ends up being interested in?

I imagine I could store the pointers in a `map`, instead, but that seems redundant: making the key have the same name as the class.

[Here](https://ideone.com/e.js/0mUO11) is an idea, but it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but I'm open to comments/criticisms/suggestions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> //unique_ptr
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class BaseFunctor{
public:
    virtual double operator()(std::vector<double> inputs) = 0;  
    virtual std::string name() = 0;  
};

class Sum : public BaseFunctor{
    double operator() (std::vector<double> inputs){ 
        double sum (0.0);
        for(auto elem : inputs)
            sum += elem;
        return sum;
    }
    std::string name() { return "sum"; }
};

class Prod : public BaseFunctor{
    double operator() (std::vector<double> inputs){ 
        double prod (1.0);
        for(auto elem : inputs)
            prod *= elem;
        return prod;
    }
    std::string name() { return "prod"; }
};

class Calculator {
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<BaseFunctor> > m_stats;
    std::vector<double> m_simple_data;
public:
    Calculator() 
        : m_simple_data({1.0, 2.0, 5.0}) {};
        
    void addStat(std::unique_ptr<BaseFunctor> stat) { 
        m_stats.insert(
            std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<BaseFunctor>>(
                stat->name(),
                std::move(stat)
            )   
        );
        //m_stats.push_back(std::move(stat)); 
    }
    
    double calc(std::string op_name){
        return (*m_stats[op_name])(m_simple_data);
    }
};

int main() {

    Calculator thing;
    thing.addStat(std::unique_ptr<BaseFunctor>(new Sum()) );
    thing.addStat(std::unique_ptr<BaseFunctor>(new Prod()) );

    std::cout << "sum: " << thing.calc("sum") << "\n";
    std::cout << "prod: " << thing.calc("prod");
    
    return 0;
}
```